# Not starting onclick action "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

```
<tr>
            <th>TH1</th>
            <th>TH2</th>
            <th>TH3</th>
            <?php
                if($account == 'admin' || $permission == 'deleting-rows')
                {
                    echo "<th><button onclick='delete_all(".$_GET['id'].")'>DELETE</button></th></tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>

function delete_all(nr)
{
    if(confirm("Do you want to delete all records?"))
    {
        window.location.href="delete-all.php?id="+nr;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have this kind of error in console "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". But everything looks good.. Please, help.

Comment: When do you get this error? And what's the final rendered output of this?

Comment: Ignore the PHP and look at the source code in the browser. You'll be able to better see where the syntax error is coming from.

Comment: After click on this button. After click it must open "delete-all.php?id=+nr", but this 
is not responding

Comment: Also, for reference `window.location.href="delete-all.php?id="+nr;` - you seem to be using a GET request to introduce changes to the application. This is very much discouraged - GET should only be retrieving data without changing anything, while POST (and possibly PUT, DELETE) would be doing the changes. The simplest reason is that if a web crawler tries to index your `delete-all.php?id=1`, `delete-all.php?id=2`, `delete-all.php?id=3`, etc pages, you'd lose all data.

Comment: `delete_all(".$_GET['id'].")` maybe the `id` is not really a real number. In that case you have to pass it as string.

Comment: @Lain "id" is IP address. But in browser it looks "delete_all(x.x.x.x)" as normal IP Adress

Comment: @pek16448 then you have invalid JS, since `1.2.3.4` is not a valid numeric literal. You need to pass this as a string.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - the syntax error is not in the PHP code itself but the JavaScript code that PHP produces.